# Using \fbox inside \section

Tags: sectioning, boxes

I want to place an `\fbox` inside of some `\part`, `\chapter`, and `\section` commands. Instead, I get this message:

```
Use of \@chapter doesn't match its definition.
```

Update:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\begin{document}
    \section{\fbox{hi}}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Using `\chapter{A \fbox{test}}` or `\section{A \fbox{test}}` works without a problem, even if you include `\tableofcontents`. Would you be able to provide an [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) that duplicates the problem?

Comment: While making the MWE, I discovered it only has problems when I add \usepackage{xcolor} to my document.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Protecting your `\fbox` in a section command (since it is [fragile](https://texfaq.org/FAQ-protect)) allows for it to be used without problem:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}% http://ctan.org/pkg/xcolor
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\section{\protect\fbox{hi}}
\section{\colorbox{green!25}{there}}
\end{document}
```

Alternatively, the [`etoolbox` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/etoolbox) provides `\robustify{<cmd>}` which can make `<cmd>` non-fragile:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{etoolbox}% http://ctan.org/pkg/etoolbox
\usepackage{xcolor}% http://ctan.org/pkg/xcolor
\robustify{\fbox}% Make \fbox non-fragile
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\section{\fbox{hi}}
\section{\colorbox{green!25}{there}}
\end{document}
```

Similar functionality is provided by [`makerobust`](http://ctan.org/pkg/makerobust). Also see the discussion [What is the difference between Fragile and Robust commands? When and why do we need \protect?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/4736/what-is-the-difference-between-fragile-and-robust-commands)

Comment: Good, that has done it! I find that introduced a new problem. The \fbox{}'s are inside \footnote{}'s which are in the section titles using \usepackage[stable]{footmisc}. The footnotes now run too long on the page (covering up the page number). Is that likely a side-effect of using \protect?

Comment: It shouldn't be. Since this may be related to [`footmisc`](http://ctan.org/pkg/footmisc), post a new question that shows this in an [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that).