# Detecting if inside \section

Tags: sectioning, conditionals

How can I make a conditional that checks if it is currently inside a `\part`, `\chapter`, or `\section`?

```
IF inside sectioning = TRUE
    DO "This text is inside a section."
ELSE
    DO "This text is not inside a section."
```

Comment: What is the end use here? Something like `\section{blah blah \mymacro{<stuff>} blah blah}` where `<stuff>` is evaluated in a certain way depending on whether you're in a `\section` or not. Better yet, provide a more detailed description of the setting using a code example that forms part of a standard document.

Comment: The sectioning text is a so called *moving argument*. It is placed multiple times: first to create the sectioning header, then it is written to the `.toc` file so that it appears in the ToC. It might also be used for PDF bookmarks in a similar way. I assume you want to have this conditional to test for potential problems with the expansion when written to the `.aux` file, right?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

ConTeXt provides system [modes](http://wiki.contextgarden.net/Modes) `*section`, `*subsection`, etc that are active inside section heads. For example

```
\def\CheckSection
    {\doifmodeelse{*section}
        {inside section}
        {outside section}}

\def\CheckSubSection
    {\doifmodeelse{*subsection}
        {inside subsection}
        {outside subsection}}

\setuppapersize[A7]
\starttext

\section{Test \CheckSection\ \CheckSubSection}

Test \CheckSection\ \CheckSubSection

\subsection{Test \CheckSection\ \CheckSubSection}

Test \CheckSection\ \CheckSubSection

\stoptext
```

gives

[image: Output]

Note that these modes are **inactive** when displaying table of contents. If you want to check if you are inside a table of contents (or list, in ConTeXt terminology), check for `*list` mode. Similarly, you can check for `*marking` mode to see if you are inside a marking (header or footer), and check for `*register` to see if you are inside a register (index, etc.).

Answer (score 9):

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcount\Level
\let\Part=\part\def\part{\global\Level=0\Part}
\let\Chapter=\chapter\def\chapter{\global\Level=1\Chapter}
\let\Section=\section\def\section{\global\Level=2\Section}
\let\Subsection=\subsection\def\subsection{\global\Level=3\Subsection}
\let\Subsubsection=\subsubsection\def\subsubsection{\global\Level=4\Subsubsection}

\def\levelText{i am inside a 
  \ifcase\the\Level part
  \or chapter
  \or section
  \or subsection
  \or subsubsection
  \else default text \fi}
\begin{document}

\part{foo}
\levelText
\section{bar}
\levelText
\subsection{baz}
\levelText

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I personally understood the question that the test should be if the macro is inside the *argument* of a sectioning command. But the question is vague, so your interpretation might be also the right one.

Comment: Herbert: To keep the user from accidentally using the newly-defined `\Part`, `\Chapter`, etc instructions, I suggest you encase the five `\let...` instructions inside `\makeatletter` ... `\makeatother` and endow each of the uppercase-letter macros with an `@` symbol.

Answer (score 4):

If your problem is related to [this other question from you](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/34553/using-fbox-inside-section) and consists in providing automatically the `\protect` before `\fbox`, you can simply say

```
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\robustify{\fbox}
```

so that any later usage of `\fbox` won't require the `\protect` even inside moving arguments such as a section title.