# No Chapter #num in the header with fancyhdr

Tags: header-footer, fancyhdr

I'm using `fancyhdr` and I want to have the header with chapters name without number opposite to section name. I've tried a lot of configurations, but none works with in this case.

How could be fixed?

ps: This short document has a different style in the Chapter page, but in the real document this is fixed.

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,twoside,titlepage,openany]{book}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage[italian]{babel}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{sectsty}

\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{
    left=35mm,
    right=30mm,
    top=27mm,
    bottom=30mm
}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}

\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\renewcommand\headrulewidth{0.4pt}
\renewcommand\footrulewidth{0.4pt}

\fancyhead[LE,RO]{\rightmark}
\fancyhead[LO,RE]{\chaptermark}

\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markboth{#1}{}}
\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{\markright{#1}}

\fancyfoot[LE,RO]{\thepage} % Left side on Even pages; Right side on Odd pages

\begin{document}
\chapter{Chapter Intro}
\lipsum
\chapter{Chapter with subsections}
\section{section foo}
\lipsum
\subsection{subsection bar}
\lipsum
\end{document}
```

Comment: Does the folowing link helps? https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/89569/custom-header-footer-rules-fancyhdr I mean the '\rhead' and '\lhead' commands... You don't need others I think

Comment: Nope, because I need a book style so I have odd and even pages with opposite headers.

I can do this, anyway, the problem is that I can't take away the "Chapter 1." from "Chapter 1. INTRO", for example.

Comment: I removed just babel and nowhere is shown a chapter (no number no name)

Comment: Exactly, this is the problem. With this configuration, there is no chapter and no name. Remove `\fancyhf{}` to see something, but this make double numbering page in the foot.

Answer (score 1):

With

```
\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markboth{#1}{}}
```

each chapter sets the left mark to the chapter name. So you have to use

```
\fancyhead[LO,RE]{\leftmark}
```

to get the desired result.

[image]

Code:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,twoside,titlepage,openany]{book}
\usepackage{lipsum}% only for dummy text

\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{
    left=35mm,
    right=30mm,
    top=27mm,
    bottom=30mm,
    headheight=13.6pt% <- added as suggest by fancyhdr
}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}

\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\renewcommand\headrulewidth{0.4pt}
\renewcommand\footrulewidth{0.4pt}

\fancyhead[LE,RO]{\rightmark}
\fancyhead[LO,RE]{\leftmark}% <- changed

\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markboth{#1}{}}
\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{\markright{#1}}

\fancyfoot[LE,RO]{\thepage}

\begin{document}
\chapter{Chapter Intro}
\lipsum
\chapter{Chapter with subsections}
\section{section foo}
\lipsum
\subsection{subsection bar}
\lipsum
\end{document}
```

---

If there are some starred chapters which should get a header entry too, use `\markboth` manually. Example:

```
\chapter*{Introduction}\markboth{Introduction}{}
```

Of course you can define a macro to do that.

Comment: I tested your code with a chapter* (see his comments on my solution) and doesn't give the chapter there... I think your way with my definitions of chapter will give the same result as mine and is simpler (Or any way you can include this option (of starred) in your code)

Comment: @koleygr Perfect! Thanks for the help. I've tried that two options, simplicity is better of course :D

Answer (score 0):

**Last Edit Answer**

With this answer you can select the depth of sectioning that appear 
in fancyhead using \MaxLevel variable. (For example if you use number 2,
only sections will be shown on fancy header)

Also, you have the extra option to use a deferent fancy head content from the name of the chapter or section etc by using starred sectioning with optional argument (something that doesn't allowed in ordinary latex)

An extra feature that may not be desired is that labels are added automaticaly
to every chapter, section or subsection as {c:1} for chapter 1 (real first)
{s:2} for second section {sss:3} for third subsubsection etc.

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,twoside,titlepage,openany]{book}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{sectsty}
\usepackage{bophook}
\usepackage{refcount}

\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{
    left=35mm,
    right=30mm,
    top=27mm,
    bottom=30mm
}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}

\newcounter{realchapter}
\newcounter{realsection}
\newcounter{realsubsection}
\newcounter{realsubsubsection}

\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\renewcommand\headrulewidth{0.4pt}
\renewcommand\footrulewidth{0.4pt}

\newcount\Level
\def\MaxLevel{3} % Change this to show only desired depth on fancy header




\def\PrevSec{}

\makeatletter
\let\oldchapter=\chapter
\def\chapter{%
\xdef\ind{c:0}
\stepcounter{realchapter}
\xdef\PrevSec{\curfmark}
\global\Level=1%
\@ifstar{\@Starred}{\@nonStarred}%
}
\def\@Starred{%
\@ifnextchar[%
{\@StarredWith}%
{\@StarredWithout}%
}      
\def\@StarredWith[#1]#2{%
\xdef\ind{c:\therealchapter}
\oldchapter*{#2}\index{\ind}\label{\ind}\def\Chaptername{#1}%
}
\def\@StarredWithout#1{%
\xdef\ind{c:\therealchapter}
\oldchapter*{#1}\index{\ind}\label{\ind}\def\Chaptername{#1}%
}
\def\@nonStarred{%
\@ifnextchar[%
{\@nonStarredWith}%
{\@nonStarredWithout}%
}
\def\@nonStarredWith[#1]#2{%
\xdef\ind{c:\therealchapter}
\oldchapter[#1]{#2}\index{\ind}\label{\ind}\def\Chaptername{#1}%
}
\def\@nonStarredWithout#1{%
\xdef\ind{c:\therealchapter}
\oldchapter{#1}\index{\ind}\label{\ind}\def\Chaptername{#1}%
}

\let\oldsection=\section
\def\section{%
\stepcounter{realsection}
\xdef\PrevSec{\curfmark}
\global\Level=2%
\@ifstar{\@StarredS}{\@nonStarredS}%
}
\def\@StarredS{%
\@ifnextchar[%
{\@StarredWithS}%
{\@StarredWithoutS}%
}      
\def\@StarredWithS[#1]#2{%
\xdef\ind{s:\therealsection}
\oldsection*{#2}\index{\ind}\label{\ind}\def\Sectionname{#1}% Here you can use starred chapter, section etc with optional argument for chaptermark or sectionmark etc
}
\def\@StarredWithoutS#1{%
\xdef\ind{s:\therealsection}
\oldsection*{#1}\index{\ind}\label{\ind}\def\Sectionname{#1}%
}
\def\@nonStarredS{%
\@ifnextchar[%
{\@nonStarredWithS}%
{\@nonStarredWithoutS}%
}
\def\@nonStarredWithS[#1]#2{%
\xdef\ind{s:\therealsection}
\oldsection[#1]{#2}\index{\ind}\label{\ind}\def\Sectionname{#2}%
}
\def\@nonStarredWithoutS#1{%
\xdef\ind{s:\therealsection}
\oldsection{#1}\index{\ind}\label{\ind}\def\Sectionname{#1}%
}

\let\oldsubsection=\subsection
\def\subsection{%
\stepcounter{realsubsection}
\xdef\PrevSec{\curfmark}
\global\Level=3%
\@ifstar{\@StarredSS}{\@nonStarredSS}%
}
\def\@StarredSS{%
\@ifnextchar[%
{\@StarredWithSS}%
{\@StarredWithoutSS}%
}      
\def\@StarredWithSS[#1]#2{%
\xdef\ind{ss:\therealsubsection}
\oldsubsection*{#2}\index{\ind}\label{\ind}\def\Subsectionname{#1}% Here you can use starred chapter, section etc with optional argument for chaptermark or sectionmark etc
}
\def\@StarredWithoutSS#1{%
\xdef\ind{ss:\therealsubsection}
\oldsubsection*{#1}\index{\ind}\label{\ind}\def\Subsectionname{#1}%
}
\def\@nonStarredSS{%
\@ifnextchar[%
{\@nonStarredWithSS}%
{\@nonStarredWithoutSS}%
}
\def\@nonStarredWithSS[#1]#2{%
\xdef\ind{ss:\therealsubsection}
\oldsubsection[#1]{#2}\index{\ind}\label{\ind}\def\Subsectionname{#1}%
}
\def\@nonStarredWithoutSS#1{%
\xdef\ind{ss:\therealsubsection}
\oldsubsection{#1}\index{\ind}\label{\ind}\def\Subsectionname{#1}%
}

\let\oldsubsubsection=\subsubsection
\def\subsubsection{%
\stepcounter{realsubsubsection}
\xdef\PrevSec{\curfmark}
\global\Level=4%
\@ifstar{\@StarredSS}{\@nonStarredSS}%
}
\def\@StarredSSS{%
\@ifnextchar[%
{\@StarredWithSSS}%
{\@StarredWithoutSSS}%
}      
\def\@StarredWithSSS[#1]#2{%
\xdef\ind{sss:\therealsubsubsection}
\oldsubsubsection*{#2}\index{\ind}\label{\ind}\def\Subsubectionname{#1}% Here you can use starred chapter, section etc with optional argument for chaptermark or sectionmark etc
}
\def\@StarredWithoutSSS#1{%
\xdef\ind{sss:\therealsubsubsection}
\oldsubsubsection*{#1}\index{\ind}\label{\ind}\def\Subsubsectionname{#1}%
}
\def\@nonStarredSSS{%
\@ifnextchar[%
{\@nonStarredWithSSS}%
{\@nonStarredWithoutSSS}%
}
\def\@nonStarredWithSSS[#1]#2{%
\xdef\ind{sss:\therealsubsubsection}
\oldsubsubsection[#1]{#2}\index{\ind}\label{\ind}\def\Subsubsectionname{#2}%
}
\def\@nonStarredWithoutSSS#1{%
\xdef\ind{sss:\therealsubsubsection}
\oldsubsubsection{#1}\index{\ind}\label{\ind}\def\Subsubsectionname{#1}%
}
\makeatother




\def\mysecdepth#1{\ifcase#1  
Part
\or \empty%
\or Sectionname%
\or Subsectionname%
\or Subsubsectionname%
\fi}


\fancyhead[LE,RO]{\fmark}
\fancyhead[LO,RE]{\smark}

\def\curfmark{\ifnum\thepage<\getpagerefnumber{\ind}\PrevSec\else\ifnum\Level>\MaxLevel\csname\mysecdepth{\MaxLevel}\endcsname\else\csname\mysecdepth{\the\Level}\endcsname\fi\fi}



\newcommand{\fmark}{\curfmark}
\newcommand{\smark}{\Chaptername}

\fancyfoot[LE,RO]{\thepage} % Left side on Even pages; Right side on Odd pages

\begin{document}

\chapter{Chapter Intro}
\lipsum
\lipsum

\chapter*{Chapter 1 with subsections}
\section{section foo 1}
\lipsum[2-13]
\subsection{subsection bar 1}
\lipsum

\chapter{Chapter 2 with subsections}
\section{section foo 2}
\lipsum[2-13]
\subsection{subsection bar 2}
\lipsum

\chapter*[Different title in fancyheader]{Chapter 3 with subsections}
\section{section foo 3}
\lipsum
\subsection{subsection bar 3}
\lipsum

the last sebsection was \ref{ss:3} with starting on page \pageref{ss:3}

\end{document}
```

(Used [Detecting if inside \section](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/34554/detecting-if-inside-section)) and from [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/378560/formatting-titles-sections-subsections-in-article/378568#378568) my answer

**Old answer**
Test this to see if it is ok

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,twoside,titlepage,openany]{book}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{sectsty}

\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{
    left=35mm,
    right=30mm,
    top=27mm,
    bottom=30mm
}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}

\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\renewcommand\headrulewidth{0.4pt}
\renewcommand\footrulewidth{0.4pt}

\fancyhead[LE,RO]{\fmark}
\fancyhead[LO,RE]{\smark}

\let\Chaptermark\chaptermark
\def\chaptermark#1{\def\Chaptername{#1}\Chaptermark{#1}}

\newcommand{\fmark}{\rightmark}
\newcommand{\smark}{\Chaptername}

\fancyfoot[LE,RO]{\thepage} % Left side on Even pages; Right side on Odd pages

\begin{document}

\chapter{Chapter Intro}
\lipsum
\lipsum

\chapter{Chapter with subsections}
\section{section foo}
\lipsum
\subsection{subsection bar}
\lipsum
\end{document}
```

Used answer here: [how to get the current chapter name, section name, subsection name, etc?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/62241/how-to-get-the-current-chapter-name-section-name-subsection-name-etc)

Comment: You can do the same as I did with chapter to the section... but I did not really understood what you want with the sections... (Numbered or not)

Comment: You are close to my idea, thanks! But I  want to remove the numbers also from chapter, leaving only the name, because I've got some `\chapter*` that breaks this things.

Comment: @IlDordollano Edited my answer but removed sections numbering too (If you want I can add it back)

Comment: Doesn't work... changing it!

Comment: Finished and works... but of course there are simpler methods

Comment: AFAIK the mark mechanism should be used for the  header entries. If you add `\lipsum[2-5]` before `\subsection{subsection bar}` in your second example, you have the header entry "subsection bar" already on page 5 while the subsection starts on top of page 6.

Comment: @esdd thanks... I found it. I don't know where it came from because I already had changed my answer when you commented. Anyway I changed the code to the tested version I had and it works

Comment: Sorry, but the issue is in the Last Edit Answer too: insert `\lipsum[2-5]` in  Chapter 1 ... before the `\subsection` command.

Comment: @esdd I could not reproduce it but found that `\lipsum[2-13]` gives the new subsection exactly on the next page reproduce the problem you mentioned... if it is not exactly on next page it doesn't have a problem. But sure it is a big problem and I don't think there is an easy way to find if the section starts on newpage... Thanks

Comment: @esdd Fixed with getpagerefnumber help... I think it is too complicated but the code gives the ability of many changes and automates things. The disadvantage is the automatic labels that have to respect the user and are using the full name of the chapter or section etc. Thanks for noticing my previous bug.