# Condition "if within another command" in LaTeX

Tags: macros

I would like to define a LaTeX (!) command which would change its behavior if it occurs withing the scope of another command. Something like:

```
\newcommand{\aaa}[1]{#1}
\newcommand{\bbb}[1] IF WITHIN \aaa{} >>> {\it #1} 
                     ELSE>                {\bf #1}
```

Sorry for the "code" but I have little idea where to start looking for it or how to formulate my question correctly.

For example,

```
\bbb{sometext}
```

prints: **sometext**

while

```
\aaa{\bbb{sometext}}
```

prints: *sometext*

What I was able to find is only a similar question from some years ago: [Detecting if inside \section](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/34554/detecting-if-inside-section). The answer was to use "modes" in ConTeXt which is impossible for me as I am restricted to LaTeX due to very specific packages I need.

Comment: Does it have to be `\bbb` detecting if it's within `\aaa`?  Could `\aaa` locally redefine `\bbb` instead?

Comment: Thank you for your comment. The latter is also an option of course but I still do not know how it could be implemented.

Comment: This question has already got its answer, I’m wondering what is the typical use of this? Any example?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

EDITED to reflect helpful insight from Jonas that the original method (setting 0/1) could be spoofed with repeated invocations of `\bbb` inside of `\aaa`.  Thus I converted over to an analogous counter approach, such that the counter value reflects the depth of nesting.

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcounter{inaaa}
\newcommand{\aaa}[1]{\stepcounter{inaaa}#1\addtocounter{inaaa}{-1}}
\newcommand{\bbb}[1]{%
  \ifnum\value{inaaa}=0\textbf{#1}\else\relax\textit{#1}\fi}
\begin{document}
\bbb{sometext}

\aaa{\bbb{sometext} text}

\aaa{\aaa{\bbb{foo}}\bbb{bar}}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much. It worked for me! (it was of course not about bold or italics)

Comment: This solution may fail if `\aaa` is used within itself, see [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/448586/47692).

Comment: @JonasGranholm While I don't claim to have tried all possibilities, I have not discovered the case you refer to.  For example, `\aaa{Here is \aaa{\bbb{sometext}}}` Puts "Here is" in roman text, and "sometext" in italic, as it should be.

Comment: `\aaa{\aaa{\bbb{foo}}\bbb{bar}}` gives _foo_ __bar__ instead of _foo_ _bar_. The problem is that the inner `\aaa` “turns off” `\inaaa` when it ends, before the second `\bbb` is evaluated.

Comment: A trick that should work is to increase and decrease `\inaaa` instead of setting it to 1 and 0, so that it measures nesting level instead.

Comment: @JonasGranholm Thanks.  I will adopt a counter approach.

Answer (score 9):

You can use the `\newif` command to define a new (very low-level) conditional and commands that alter the conditional test:

```
\documentclass{article}

\newif\ifinsideaaa

\newcommand{\aaa}[1]{%
    \insideaaatrue
    #1%
    \insideaaafalse
}
\newcommand{\bbb}[1]{
    \ifinsideaaa
    {\itshape #1}%
    \else
    {\bfseries #1}%
    \fi
}

\begin{document}

\bbb{Some text outside of \texttt{\string\aaa}}

\aaa{\bbb{Some text inside of \texttt{\string\aaa}}}

\end{document}
```

[image]

The new commands defined by `\newif\if<foo>` are:

- `\if<foo>`: the conditional check to be used with `\if<foo> ... \else ... \fi`,
- `\<foo>true`: the command that sets the condition to true, and
- `\<foo>false`: the command that sets the condition to false.

As a side note, you should use `\itshape` and `\bfseries` instead of `\it` and `\bf` in LaTeX. The latter are outdated.

Comment: Thank you very much for your explanation! \it and \bf are just examples. It's actually about other command which would just distract if mentioned.

Comment: This solution may fail if `\aaa` is used within itself, see [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/448586/47692).

Answer (score 4):

I tend to avoid the TeX primitives `\if..` whenever avoiding them is possible.

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
\newcommand\My@CheckWhetherinAAA{}
\newcommand\My@SetInAAATrue{\let\My@CheckWhetherinAAA=\@firstoftwo}
\newcommand\My@SetInAAAFalse{\let\My@CheckWhetherinAAA=\@secondoftwo}
\global\My@SetInAAAFalse

\newcommand{\aaa}[1]{%
  \My@CheckWhetherinAAA{#1}%
                       {\My@SetInAAATrue#1\My@SetInAAAFalse}%
}%

\newcommand{\bbb}[1]{%
  \My@CheckWhetherinAAA{\textit}%
                       {\textbf}%
  {#1}%
}
%
% The result of the following is the same but LaTeX has to shuffle
% around more tokens:
%
% \newcommand{\bbb}[1]{%
%   \My@CheckWhetherinAAA{\textit{#1}}%
%                        {\textbf{#1}}%
%   }%
%
\makeatother


\begin{document}
\bbb{some text}

\aaa{\bbb{some text}}

\aaa{\aaa{\bbb{some text}} \aaa{\bbb{some more text}}}

\begingroup \aaa{\aaa{\bbb{some text}} \endgroup\aaa{\bbb{some more text}}}

\bbb{some text}

\end{document}
```

With this approach, the tokens forming the argument of `\aaa` get doubled and gobbled.

This can be avoided by defining another helper-macro:

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
\newcommand\My@CheckWhetherinAAA{}
\newcommand\My@SetInAAATrue{\let\My@CheckWhetherinAAA=\@firstoftwo}
\newcommand\My@SetInAAAFalse{\let\My@CheckWhetherinAAA=\@secondoftwo}
\newcommand\My@SetAAAconditions[1]{\My@SetInAAATrue#1\My@SetInAAAFalse}%
\global\My@SetInAAAFalse

\newcommand{\aaa}[1]{%
  \My@CheckWhetherinAAA{\@firstofone}%
                       {\My@SetAAAconditions}%
                       {#1}%
}%

\newcommand{\bbb}[1]{%
  \My@CheckWhetherinAAA{\textit}%
                       {\textbf}%
  {#1}%
}
%
% The result of the following is the same but LaTeX has to shuffle
% around more tokens:
%
% \newcommand{\bbb}[1]{%
%   \My@CheckWhetherinAAA{\textit{#1}}%
%                        {\textbf{#1}}%
%   }%
%
\makeatother


\begin{document}
\bbb{some text}

\aaa{\bbb{some text}}

\aaa{\aaa{\bbb{some text}} \aaa{\bbb{some more text}}}

\begingroup \aaa{\aaa{\bbb{some text}} \endgroup\aaa{\bbb{some more text}}}

\bbb{some text}

\end{document}
```

Comment: `\global`, `\makeatletter`, `\makeatother`, `\@firstoftwo`, and `\@secondoftwo` seems like a lot of machinery to avoid a tex primitive.  And should `\My@SetInaFalse` be `\My@SetInAAAFalse`?

Comment: @Teepeemm Indeed, should be `\My@SetInAAAFalse`. I avoid things like `\if...#1...\else...\fi` because providing unbalanced `\if`/`\else`/`\fi`as components of arguments might cause problems... As a rule of thumb macros get a little more "user-proof" by avoiding putting an argument (where you don't know what tokens the user will provide) somewhere between `\if..\else..\fi`. When I use them, I often do `\if..\expandafter\@firstoftwo\else\expandafter\@secondoftwo\fi{<true-case-stuff with macro arguments>}{false-case-stuff with macro arguments>}`

Answer (score 4):

[Siracusa's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/448433/47692) may fail if `\aaa` is used within itself, as in the following example:

```
\aaa{
    \aaa{\bbb{foo}}
    \bbb{bar}}
```

This will give *foo* **bar** instead of *foo* *bar*.

[Ulrich's](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/448476/47692) and the [accepted answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/448432/47692) do not have this weakness and are good solutions, especially if you want to define both versions of `\bbb` at the same time.
A quicker and simpler way that also behaves as expected in the example above is to let `\aaa` redefine `\bbb` locally, as [Teepeemm commented](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/448430/condition-if-within-another-command-in-latex#comment1126655_448430):

```
\newcommand{\bbb}[1]{\textbf{#1}}
\newcommand{\aaa}[1]{\bgroup\def\bbb##1{\textit{##1}}#1\egroup}
```

The double `##` in the second line is needed because it is a definition inside another definition.

(This method is by the way also useful if `\bbb` should only be defined inside `\aaa` – just remove the first line.)

Comment: It looks like you can also take Ulrich's of delaying `#1` and say `\newcommand{\bbb}{\textbf}`.  It looks like that lets you avoid `##1` entirely.

Comment: Indeed. I included the full form since OP mentioned replacing the command with something more complicated. Another way to avoid `##1` is to add `\newcommand{\bbbinaaa}[1]{\textit{#1}}` and use `\newcommand{\aaa}[1]{\bgroup\let\bbb\bbbinaaa#1\egroup}` instead.

Comment: @JonasGranholm Defining both versions of `\bbb` at the same time is recommendable only in case there are more macros wherein `\bbb` shall work in the same way in which it shall work within `\aaa`.